# Switching the components of $G\times G$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, group-actions

Consider the direct product $G \times G$, where $G$ is a finite group. 
There is a map $s:G\times G\to G\times G$ which switches the components: $(g,h)\mapsto (h,g)$, which is clearly an isomorphism of groups, or even an action of $S_2$ on $G\times G$.

The generalization to many factors is obvious.

Has this been studied? Does this have a name? Is there a reference?

Comment: Yes, this has certainly been studied in many ways. Do you have something more specific in mind? As a note a similar thing is what happens when you have iterated tensor products of a vector space, where you also have an action of the symmetric group but also of the general linear group (acting on the vector spaces themselves), leading to Schur-Weyl duality

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product .

Comment: It gives rise to the semidirect product $S_2 \ltimes (G \times G)$.

Comment: @MattSamuel The wreath product is *exactly* what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @geodude No problem. I'll put it in an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, what you're looking for is in fact the [wreath product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product). Suppose we are given a finite set $A$, a group $H$ acting on $A$ and any group $G$. Let $G^A$ be the direct product of $|A|$ copies of $G$, which we consider as the group of functions $f:A\to G$ with pointwise multiplication.

The wreath product $G\ \mathrm{wr}_A H$ is the semidirect product $G^A\rtimes H$ where for $h\in H$ and $f\in G^A$ we have
$$hf(a)h^{-1}=f(h^{-1}a)$$
This allows us to study the interaction of the group $H$ acting on $A$ with the direct product of $G$ indexed by $A$, permuting the factors as in your question. See the article for examples and literature.